# How to use Win32Api in C# Windows Service App

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-services

I'm creating a windows service app in visual studio and I want to get the currently active window title.
below is the code I have tried but the function GetForegroundWindow() returns 0 every time.
Is it okay to use win32api in windows services?

```
public partial class My_Service: ServiceBase
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

    public My_Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer.Interval = 10000; //number in milisecinds  
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string title = GetActivewindow();
        WriteToFile("Service is recall at " + title + DateTime.Now);

    }

    public void WriteToFile(string Message)
    {
       ....
    }

    public string GetActivewindow()
    {
        const int nChars = 256;
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        string title = "- ";
        IntPtr handle; 
        handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        if( GetWindowText(handle,buff,nChars) > 0)
        {
            title = buff.ToString();
        }
        return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: of course ok. but service run on another winstation/desktop

Comment: Services typically run in session id 0 which doesn't have windows. It's not going to read the windows of your session... because it cannot. So what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Run an application on the user's desktop and then use ipc to communicate with your service

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I want to track the different application usage on PC. so I thought to build a windows service in order to achieve this, which will keep running in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments, and also according to the document: [About Window Stations and Desktops - Window Station and Desktop Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/about-window-stations-and-desktops).

Your service may be running under `Service-0x0-3e7$\default`, but the foreground window you want to retrieve is in the default desktop of the interactive window station (`Winsta0\default`)

> The interactive window station is the only window station that can
>   display a user interface or receive user input. It is assigned to the
>   logon session of the interactive user, and contains the keyboard,
>   mouse, and display device. It is always named "WinSta0". All other
>   window stations are noninteractive, which means they cannot display a
>   user interface or receive user input.

That means you cannot use `GetForegroundWindow` directly from the service. You could create a child process in `Winsta0\default` and redirect its output. Then call `GetForegroundWindow` in the child process and output.

Sample(removed error checking):

Child:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
            string title = "- ";
            IntPtr handle;
            handle = GetForegroundWindow();
            if (GetWindowText(handle, buff, nChars) > 0)
            {
                title = buff.ToString();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(title);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;

namespace WindowsService3
{
    public partial class MyNewService : ServiceBase
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public Int32 cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public Int32 dwX;
            public Int32 dwY;
            public Int32 dwXSize;
            public Int32 dwYSize;
            public Int32 dwXCountChars;
            public Int32 dwYCountChars;
            public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
            public Int32 dwFlags;
            public Int16 wShowWindow;
            public Int16 cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public Int32 dwProcessId;
            public Int32 dwThreadId;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int nLength;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public int bInheritHandle;
        }


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
            IntPtr hToken,
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
            IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            uint dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            IntPtr lpCurrentDirectory,
            ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool CreatePipe(
            ref IntPtr hReadPipe,
            ref IntPtr hWritePipe,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes,
            uint nSize);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool ReadFile(
            IntPtr hFile,
            byte[] lpBuffer,
            uint nNumberOfBytesToRead,
            out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead,
            IntPtr lpOverlapped);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
        [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool WTSQueryUserToken(UInt32 SessionId, out IntPtr hToken);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr hProcess, uint dwMilliseconds);
        public MyNewService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("Path\\Log.txt"))
            {
                IntPtr read = new IntPtr();
                IntPtr write = new IntPtr();
                IntPtr read2 = new IntPtr();
                IntPtr write2 = new IntPtr();
                SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                saAttr.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
                saAttr.bInheritHandle = 1;
                saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;

                CreatePipe(ref read, ref write, ref saAttr, 0);
                CreatePipe(ref read2, ref write2, ref saAttr, 0);

                uint CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000;
                int STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100;
                STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
                si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STARTUPINFO));
                si.hStdOutput = write;
                si.hStdError = write;
                si.hStdInput = read2;
                si.lpDesktop = "Winsta0\\default";
                si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

                IntPtr hToken;
                bool err = WTSQueryUserToken(WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), out hToken);
                string path = "Path\\ConsoleApp1.exe";
                if (CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, path, null, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, ref si, out pi))
                {
                    uint ret = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 2000); //wait for the child process exit.
                    if (ret == 0)
                    {
                        byte[] title = new byte[200];
                        uint reads = 0;
                        CloseHandle(write);
                        err = ReadFile(read, title, 200, out reads, IntPtr.Zero);
                        string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(title).Replace("\0","").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");

                        sw.WriteLine(result);

                    }
                }
                CloseHandle(read2);
                CloseHandle(write2);
                CloseHandle(read);
            }

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,@Sameer, is this sample helpful to you? Please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it does solve the issue.

Comment: thanks for suggesting this. I'm trying to implement it now

Comment: It's a nice solution. Maybe does some way to get a foreground window on event exist?